# History process

Tags: linux, command-line, process, thread

Is there a command line to retrieve all information like pid tid of threads in Linux? For instance if one process has dead before the command ps runs. The command does not find the process

Answer (score 0):

No, that history is not kept by Linux, so there is no tool that could query it.